# Get all applications where count of positions more then 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

`LoanApplications (Id, Name, CreationDate, LoanApplicationStatusId)`

`Positions(Id, Name, CreationDate, LoanApplicationId)`

I need to find all loan applications that have more than 1 position and update LoanApplicationStatusId  to 2

I write code to get these LoanApplications like this

```
    SELECT e.Id, count(Name) FROM LoanApplications e
INNER JOIN Positions d ON e.Id=d.LoanApplicationId
GROUP BY e.Id
HAVING COUNT(Name)>1
```

But I don't understand how to make an update now.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select `id` of apps which have more than one row, and use it in UPDATE as a condition

```sql
UPDATE LoanApplications 
JOIN ( SELECT LoanApplicationId
       FROM Positions
       GROUP BY LoanApplicationId
       HAVING COUNT(LoanApplicationId) > 1 ) multi_positional ON id = LoanApplicationId
SET LoanApplicationStatusId = 2
```

---

> Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once Got this stuff – Eugene Sukh

Convert this query to

```sql
UPDATE LoanApplications 
JOIN ( SELECT LoanApplicationId
       FROM Positions
       GROUP BY LoanApplicationId
       HAVING COUNT(LoanApplicationId) > 1 ) multi_positional 
SET LoanApplicationStatusId = 2
WHERE LoanApplications.id = multi_positional.LoanApplicationId
```

Comment: Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once


Got this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Straight ahead would be a simple subselect

```
UPDATE LoanApplications l
SET LoanApplicationStatusId = 2
where (select count(1) from Positions p where p.LoanApplicationId = l.id) > 1
```